# Compiling a Qt Application using Dev C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, dev-c++

I wrote a small Qt application in Dev-C++ as shown:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!"); 
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I am quite sure I've done everything necessary to start creating Qt applications such as install Qt5.3.2, setup the system environment variables, etc. However, when trying to compile the program in Dev-C++, I get an error saying:

```
[Error]: QApplication: No such file or directory
```

After closely following instructions from other tutorials, I still cannot get the program to compile.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a qmake to build?

Comment: I tried building using qmake earlier, through the Qt5.3 console . All seemed fine until I was instructed to enter the 'make' command to finally compile the project. I received an error saying: 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: I have installed Windows 7.

Comment: You probably need to get a MinGw installation and a suitable c++ compiler toolchain first.  Why don't you use QtCreator? It comes ready made with all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev-C++ is based on mingw, so you should install Qt compiled for mingw on Windows. Then indeed you should use qmake to generate Makefiles. For compilation you should use the make utility provided by mingw distribution shipped with Dev-C++ (the name of this utility might not be exactly 'make' in mingw)

Comment: It's actually `make` in MinGw/MSys.